# Notification and indication - BLE, Glucose service

Tags: notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I'm trying to get glucose measurements from glucose device (Contour One Plus) with Bluetooth LE, using the TBluetoothLE component in Delphi. I can:
- connect to device
- discover GATT services
- discover GATT characteristics
and now Im trying to set notification for Glucose Measurement Characteristic and indication to Record Access Control Point Characteristic.

I wrote two procedures for enabling:

- notification for Glucose Measurement:

```
procedure TForm6.enableGlucoseMeasurementNotification(
  const ACharacteristic: TBluetoothGattCharacteristic);
  var
    ADescriptor: TBluetoothGattDescriptor;
    AValues : TBytes;
begin
   BluetoothLE1.DiscoveredDevices[0].SetCharacteristicNotification(FGlucoseMeasurementGattCharact, true);
   ADescriptor := FGlucoseMeasurementGattCharact.Descriptors[0];  // czy aby na pewno [0]... ?

   SetLength(AValues, 2);
   AValues[0] := $01;
   AValues[1] := $00;

   ADescriptor.SetValue(AValues);
   BluetoothLE1.DiscoveredDevices[0].WriteDescriptor(ADescriptor);
end;
```

- indication for Record Access Control Point:

```
procedure TForm6.enableRecordAccessControlPointIndication(
  const ACharacteristic: TBluetoothGattCharacteristic);
  var
  ADescriptor: TBluetoothGattDescriptor;
  AValues: TBytes;
begin
  BluetoothLE1.DiscoveredDevices[0].SetCharacteristicNotification(FRecordAccessControlPoint, true);
  ADescriptor := FRecordAccessControlPoint.Descriptors[0];

  SetLength(AValues, 2);
  AValues[0] := $02;
  AValues[1] := $00;

  ADescriptor.SetValue(AValues);
  BluetoothLE1.DiscoveredDevices[0].WriteDescriptor(ADescriptor);
end;
```

I am based on nRF Connect but I dont understand few things.
My question is, where I should run these two procedures? In OnServicesDiscovered?
Are my procedures correct? 
And what is the next step to get values from RACP? I should just write byte value (for example 0x01) to RACP?

Comment: I suggest you have a look the
"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Device Sensors and Services\Bluetooth\HeartRateMonitor" sample.

Comment: So "SubscribeToCharacteristic(device, characteristic)" is responsible for setting indications/notifications to characteristic? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I don't know your specifications,  but I use the SubscribeToCharacteristic and after that I use the onCharacteristicRead event to get the data from my device. Also I use the WriteCharacteristic to send data to my device.

Comment: So first, I should use SubscribeToCharacteristic,
and then -> when I want to send values (bytes) to my device -> I should use just .setValue() (like in my previous procedure) or use WriteCharacteristic?

I need to write to first characteristic 0x01 - RecordAccessControlPoint, and read data from: GlucoseMeasurement Characteristic.

Comment: You should SubscribeToCharacteristic to the read Characteristic and use the  onCharacteristicRead event. And use the write Characteristic SetValue(...) and after that use BluetoothLE1.WriteCharacteristic( ..., ) method to write to the device eg.: FWWRITECHARACT.SetValue(wWrBytes); where FWWRITECHARACT: TBluetoothGattCharacteristic; and use BluetoothLE1.WriteCharacteristic(FBLEDevice, FWWRITECHARACT);

Comment: I think I was able to turn on indications and notifications (SubscribeToCharacteristic enables only notifications). Then, I use: .SetValue -> to write bytes to characteristic (via .WriteCharacteristic method). 
And where should the data be collected?

Comment: "You should SubscribeToCharacteristic to the read Characteristic and use the onCharacteristicRead event." in the onCharacteristicRead event you can use the ACharacteristic.Value

Comment: Finally, I implemented it. Thanks for the tips :)